# change region block in module

Tags: 7, blocks

I want when a node saved,one block region be change.

for example: when a node be save,"user-login block" move to the content region.

please help me for resolve this problem.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

try the context module and use node as the context and blocks as the reaction. you should be able to figure out the rest :)